# Целесообразно ли использовать safemysql.class.php?

Tags: php, sql

Скажите, целесообразно ли использовать класс safemysql.class.php для мелких проектов, где требуется БД? Например, легкие лендинги, визитки, мини-магазины. Класс стареньких, но мне комфортно с ним работать. Хочу изучить фреймворк Laravel, но он для более тяжелых проектов, а для мелочей незачем лишними файлами захломлять проект.... А есть что-то наподобии safemysql.class, только более новее?

Comment: Не нужно бояться "захламления", это дурацкая фобия. Нет никакой разницы, для какого проекта использовать Laravel. Если же говорить о safemysql, то его можно использовать и с ларавелью

Comment: @Ипатьев скажите, а в Laravel, если проект выкладывать на хост, нужно загружать все файлы или его можно скомпилировать в public со всеми blade шаблонами и backend частью ?

Comment: ничего не понял. при чем здесь blade шаблоны? Любой сайт на фрейморке состоит из двух частей - файлов  фреймворка и собственных файлов сайта. файлы фреймворка не "компилируются", а загружаются с помощью композера. Файлы проекта очевидно надо заливать. Те что сам писал.